# Combining data in a cell if criteria is met and then delete duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel 365 project I have 3 columns, 2 that need to be tested and 1 that needs data combining.

- Column A is a 7-digit "Drawing Number" (e.g. 005-0035)
- Column B is a "Revision Number" (e.g. 0)
- Column C are "Color Codes" that are comma delimited (e.g. GR, NL, TI, G0), some only containing one Color Code.
- Note: there are 3,000 rows.

1. I need to test Column A and determine if there are any duplicates.
2. If so, combine all of their Column C data into the cell of the row which contains the highest Revision Number, found in Column B, but only unique Color Codes (i.e. if both rows contain the same, or some of the same Color Code(s), don't duplicate that particular Color Code, as they must remain unique and comma delimited).
3. Then, delete duplicate rows based on the Drawing Number (Column A), but keeping the row with the highest Revision Number (Column B). **Note:** some duplicate rows will have identical Revision Numbers; in that case keep the row with the combination of Color Codes (Column C) from step #2.

Example:
If there are 5 rows that are duplicates based on the Drawing Number (Column A), combine the Color Codes (Column C) into the row with the highest Revision Number (Column B). Finally, delete the other duplicate rows, even if they have duplicate Revision Numbers (Column B); leaving the one row with the combined Color Code (Column C).

I don't have sample code because it is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Can the sheet be sorted ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Absolutely. The sheet can be sorted in advance.

Comment: @Ike - I did attempt this via sorting and Excel 365 features, but combining values with other cell's criteria isn't something Excel can do w/o VBA intervention. I am at a loss for the VBA code on this one.

Comment: This would be pretty straightforward in Power Query. And examples abound in this forum for grouping and returning what you describe.  Include Power Query in your search and you'll find some examples.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you! I will test the code starting tomorrow and post feedback on Monday.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it works really well, except that it's keeping duplicate Color Codes in column 3. Is there a way we can ensure that duplicate entries are not included?

>        Else
>            ws.Cells(i, 3) = Join(dict.keys, ",")
>            dict.RemoveAll

Comment: Hmm. I suggested Power Query. The code you posted is VBA.  You've not shown any example of your data, or the code you are using.  So I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data then scan upwards deleting duplicate rows by comparing with the row above. Use a Dictionary to compile list of unique color codes.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
     
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
    
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("B1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
       
    ' scan
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        dict(Trim(ws.Cells(i, 3))) = 1
        ' compare with line above
        If ws.Cells(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 1) Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = Join(dict.keys, ",")
            dict.RemoveAll
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```